# Flickering Sidebar on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sidebar, flicker

I have a sidebar that continually checks the users scrollposition and depending on their position, changes the background image of a specific image on a sidebar when needed to indicate which section on the page is being viewed. When viewing this sidebar locally, I see the sidebar flicker.

After uploading it to my site and viewing it there, the flickering stopped, but just in case, I wanted to know if anyone knows why and how to stop it. My website where the sidebar can be viewed in action (it's the sidebar on the left with number 1,2,3, and 4) is [here](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/nationals_website/blinker.html). My code is below.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
var greenheight = document.getElementById('welcome_logo').offsetHeight;
var redheight = document.getElementById('slideins').offsetHeight;
var blueheight = document.getElementById('section_overview').offsetHeight;
var yellowheight = document.getElementById('howsiteworks').offsetHeight;

if($(window).scrollTop() > redheight){
    if (navslide != 2) {
    if($(window).scrollTop() < greenheight+redheight){
        $('#side2').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side2_over.fw.png)");
        $('#side1').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side1.fw.png)");
        $('#side3').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side3.fw.png)");
        $('#side4').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side4.fw.png)");
        var navslide = 2
    }
    }
}

if($(window).scrollTop() < redheight)
if (navslide != 1) {
{
        $('#side1').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side1_over.fw.png)");
        $('#side2').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side2.fw.png)");
        $('#side3').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side3.fw.png)");
        $('#side4').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side4.fw.png)");
        var navslide = 1
}
}

if($(window).scrollTop() > redheight+greenheight){
    if (navslide!=3) {
    if($(window).scrollTop() < greenheight+redheight+blueheight){
        $('#side3').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side3_over.fw.png)");
        $('#side1').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side1.fw.png)");
        $('#side2').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side2.fw.png)");
        $('#side4').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side4.fw.png)");
        var navslide = 3
    }
    }
}

if($(window).scrollTop() > redheight+greenheight+blueheight){
    if (navslide!=4) {
    if($(window).scrollTop() < greenheight+redheight+blueheight+yellowheight){
        $('#side4').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side4_over.fw.png)");
        $('#side1').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side1.fw.png)");
        $('#side2').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side2.fw.png)");
        $('#side3').css("background-image", "url(images/sidebar/side3.fw.png)");
        var navslide = 4
    }
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using different images for every possible scenario (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 1-over, 2-over, 3-over, 4-over, etc). The `over` images aren't loaded in the browser when scrolling. In other words, as you'r scrolling, your CSS goes, "*I need to switch images. Let me remove the current image first... **[image disappears]** OK... now let me download this other image. Aaaaaaand, done! **[image reappears]***" This is the "blinking" that you're seeing.

Two basic techniques you can apply to mitigate this are:

1. Pre-loading the relevant images:

   - http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/
   - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/image-preloader/
2. Use sprites (a single image instead of 8)

   - http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/
   - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having some trouble finding the best way to preload and the sprite is taking a lot of time as well. I noticed when on the site, it doesn't flicker on any of my browsers, only locally. Do you think it is worth it to fix?